# fullCalendar V3 Tool tip doesnt show on hover

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, tooltip, fullcalendar-3

Does Fullcalendar V3 or V5 support Tool tip by default? in the docs they we should use eventrender does that mean eventrender needs to be used with external libraries to get the Tooltip? does fullcalendar provide any event/Api to get the Tooltip?
or do we need to use Bootstrap or Jquery to get Tool tip functionality?

below is my js code, when i hover on my event it doesnt show any tool tip and there are no errors in console.

`JET`

```
function renderData($,self,data)  {

    self = this;
    this.events = [];
      data.forEach(element => {
    const obj ={};
    const extendedProps ={};
        var teststr1 = (element.TABLEX_LITM.value).concat(" - ",(element.TABLEX_DOCO.value));
        var teststr2 = (element.TABLEX_DL01.value).concat(" - ",teststr1);
        obj.title = teststr2,
        obj.start = new Date(element.TABLEX_DRQJ.value),
        obj.end= new Date(element.TABLEX_STRT.value),
        extendedProps.QuantityOrdered = element.TABLEX_UORG.value,
        extendedProps.QuantityCompleted = element.TABLEX_SOQS.value,
        obj.extendedProps = extendedProps,
        events.push(obj); 
});   

  
    this.calendar = $ ('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {
    editable: true,
    weekends : false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper:true,
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    displayEventTime: false,
    header:{
        left : 'prev,next,today',
        center : 'title',
        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },  
    
    events: events,
   
    
    eventRender: function (events, element) {
     
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        element.click(function() {
           
            $("#startTime").html(formatDate(events.start));
            $("#endTime").html(formatDate(events.end));
            $("#QuantityOrdered").html(events.extendedProps.QuantityOrdered);   
            $("#QuantityCompleted").html(events.extendedProps.QuantityCompleted); 
            $("#eventContent").dialog({ modal: true, title: events.title, width:350});
           
        });
        
          var tooltip = new Tooltip(eventInfo.el, {        
                // title: eventInfo.event.extendedProps.description,
                title: eventInfo.events.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body'
            });
        
    },
}); 

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({  
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).tooltip({
            title: event.title,
            container: "body"
        });
    }
});

}
 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var chartModel = new ChartModel();
        getE1Data(chartModel,(status)=>{
            ko.applyBindings(chartModel, document.getElementById('calendar'));
        });
    }); 
 });
```

`JET`

```
  <div class = "container">
    <div id = "calendar"> 
    <oj-table id='table' aria-label='Departments Table'
        data='[[dataprovider]]'
        columns='[[columns]]'
        style='width: 100%; height: 700px;'>   
    </oj-table>
    </div>
    
 <div id="eventContent" title="Event Details" style="display:none;">
    Start Date: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
    Requested Date: <span id="endTime"></span><br>
    Quantity Ordered: <span id="QuantityOrdered"></span><br>
    Quantity Completed: <span id="QuantityCompleted"></span><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: `Does Fullcalendar V3 or V5 support Tool tip by default?`...neither one "supports" tooltips. They don't need to. A tooltip is something you can add to _any_ HTML element. You can add a tooltip to anything in fullCalendar, or to anything else anywhere in your page. Fullcalendar does not provide any functionality itself for creating tooltips, so yes you should use an external library to provide that (unless you prefer to write the functionality yourself, of course). There are many providers of such libraries, you are not required to use any particular one.

Comment: As for your specific code, what mainly seems to have happened is that you've got very confused between the syntax for fullCalendar 3 and fullCalendar 5. Try to follow the documentation and examples only for your version. You seem to be using version 3, so https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender is what you need. There's even a link to a live demo whose source code you can copy. In your code, `eventInfo.el` will not exist, because `eventsInfo` doesn't exist. I'm very surprised this doesn't produce a console error, actually. You probably want to use `element` instead.

Comment: `eventInfo.events` also doesn't exist... and should also produce an error. Just `events` should work. `extendedProps.description` makes no sense because you didn't add a `description` to your events in the JET code. And `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({  
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).tooltip({
            title: event.title,
            container: "body"
        });
    }
});` is just creating a second, empty calendar, so I've no idea what you were trying to do there, that just needs removing.

Comment: BTW rather than doing `element.click(function() {` in the eventRender, you should use fullCalendar's ready-made eventClick callback.... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventClick . `element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');` should not be necessary because your events don't have a `url` property, so fullCalendar will not turn them into a link anyway.